# Include in android using java

Tags: android, include

I have a header view which contains 4 buttons. When I click each of these 4 buttons it should start  four different activities. And also I want these buttons in every view of my application.

I can include this header view using include tag. But how can I include the java code (button click etc) in every activities?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate class which will get the buttons as parameters and which will create and set the appropriate onClick listeners. Then just call the class from where you need. Like this:

```
public class ButtonInitializer {

  private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

  public ButtonInitializer(Button btn1, Button btn2/* and another 2 here*/) {
     this.btn1 = btn1;
     this.btn2 = btn2;
     this.btn3 = btn3;
     this.btn4 = btn4;
  }

  public void init() {
     btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
           // your code
        }
     }
     // and for other buttons
   }
```

in your activity:

```
new ButtonInitializer(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4).init();
```

Comment: please tell me how to use this in my java class.

Comment: @sunit he already shows you how to use it. Ie new ButtonInitializer(button1,button2,button3, etc).init();

Comment: @sunit you can do it in 2 ways : first one is as Vladimir mentioned above by creating a seperate class for this header and initialize and call functions of it in every activity. Second way is you no need t create a seperate claas. but you give the same coding in every activity you created. that means by including the hreader in each activity, the buttons become the property of each activity. So you can call each button with findViewById() directly, and can give functionality like other views of this class.