# android: problem when including a layout

Tags: android, layout, include

I have included one header view to every views in my application. And also can implement  button click etc to this header with the help of answer :

[Include in android using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387718/include-in-android-using-java)

But my requirement is on button click, it should start another activity. when I click the button, it stopped suddently. But other activitites like Toast, button.setText() etc is working fine on button click.

### Home.class

```
 TextView txtMarket = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMarket);
 TextView txtNews = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNews);
 ImageButton imgLogout=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgLogout);
 ImageButton imgDashBoard=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgDashBoard);
 Header objHeader=new Header(imgLogout,txtMarket,txtNews,imgDashBoard,getBaseContext());
 objHeader.init();
```

### Header.class

```
 //in Header class
 public Header(ImageButton btnLogin,TextView txtMarket,TextView txtNews,ImageButton imgDashBoard,Context context) 
 {     
          this.btnLogin = btnLogin; 
     this.txtMarket = txtMarket;     
     this.txtNews = txtNews; 
     this.imgDashBoard = imgDashBoard; 
     this.context=context;
 }
 public void init() 
 {  
      btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {              
           public void onClick(View view)
      {
            Intent loginIntent=new Intent();                               Toast.makeText(context, "u clicked the button", 1).show();
       loginIntent.setClass(view.getContext(),login.class);
       startActivity(loginIntent);
           }
});
}
```

Please help me friends....

### Edited

When I am defining like :

Intent loginIntent=new Intent(Home.this,login.class);

then it shows an error :

"No enclosing instance of the type loginHome is accessible in scope"

And if I am giving like :

When I am defining like :

Intent loginIntent=new Intent(Header.this,login.class);

then it  caught NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Did you edit the `manifest.xml` with inserting your new activity?
Like:

```
<activity android:name=".NewActivityName" />
```

Comment: Please try to define the Intent in one line:
Intent loginIntent=new Intent(--ClassName--.this,login.class);

Comment: i defined like : Intent loginIntent=new Intent(Home.this,login.class); But still not working.

Comment: Then please describe, what "stopped suddently" means? Error message on your phone? Error message from the debugger.
This might be useful in this situation, because for me, the stuff i see is correct and should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the context variable from your constructor :

```
loginIntent.setClass(Header.this.context,login.class);
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the exception, like the concerned line in your code?

Comment: Exception is caught when executing this line : startActivity(loginIntent);

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the "context" you give to your constructor. Be sure it's the activity context